# (Java) List types and inheritance

Tags: java, list, inheritance

I've a question about inherited classes and `List` types. Imagine that you've created a class called `Polygon` with some methods (calculate perimeter, area, etc) and a class called `Triangle` that extends `Polygon`. At the same time, in your Main class, you've created a `List` type that saves `Polygon` objects. Everything belongs to the same package.

My doubt it's the next one: if I create an object from type `Triangle`, can I save it into this last one `List`?

Example:

**Class Polygon**

```
public class Polygon{

//All his methods


}
```

**Class Triangle**

```
public class Triangle extends Polygon{

//All his methods

}
```

**Main Class**

```
public static void main (String[] args){

List<Polygon> listPolygon = new ArrayList <Polygon> ();
Triangle example = new Triangle();

listPolygon.add(example);

}
```

Thank you a lot and sorry for my possible bad English. I'm practicing a lot right now.

Comment: You already have the code, but you ask us *"can I"*? Why don't just try it?

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry Tom if it's obvious but I'm just learning right now, and if it's not possible I was expecting a 'no' answer followed by an article explaining to me why it's not possible, or an answer offering me an alternative solution.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "if it's obvious". You already have this code, but you haven't tried it? Not once? If you would do that, you would have your answer.

Comment: @Tom Ok, sorry. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: So please try your code. If you don't understand _why_ it behaves like that, then you can update your question, because this is something we can talk about. But please try it first :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of your question.

If your question is can you do this:

```
List<Polygon> polygonList = new ArrayList<Polygon>();
Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
polygonList.add(triangle);
```

the answer is **yes**, because a `Triangle` is a `Polygon`.

If the question is, can you do this:

```
List<Triangle> triangleList = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
List<Polygon> polygonList = triangleList;
```

the answer is **no**, because a `List<Triangle>` is not a `List<Polygon>`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) for more details.

If you are using an IDE, such as eclipse or IntelliJ, you should quickly find out what you can or cannot do, as you get helpful error messages.

Comment: You can link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p) if OP is curious why the second case won't work :).

Comment: Thank you a lot to both of you for taking your time to answer me. Have a good day! :)